# MediaLink Bluetooth with OSMC (KODI)

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, keyboard, osmc

I have a bluetooth keyboard bought for tablet usage. Since I lost the dongle, I got the MediaLink bluetooth dongle. I was able to pair it with my laptop but when I plugged-in the dongle to my Raspberry pi 3(KODI installed), it is not paring.

I checked the log using "dmesg" and I saw the command timeout exception. I tried to google around and found some post where it pointed to download the driver file. I did that but still i am getting the same error.

Could you please help me on how I could fix this issue.

Regards,
Raaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by buying a new dongle [Plugable USB Bluetooth 4.0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009ZIILLI). After that I inserted and checked the dmesg. It recognized the device and followed these instructions [Connecting A Bluetooth Device](https://osmc.tv/wiki/general/connecting-a-bluetooth-device/) to pair the device.